# type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' when parsing Firebase response

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My parsing code is like this.

```
  class Model {
      List<Info>? info,
      idx,
      name,
      image,
      kcal,
      effect,
      keep,
      tip,
      youtube01,
      youtube02,
      youtube03,
      season;

      Model(
      {this.info,
      this.idx,
      this.name,
      this.image,
      this.kcal,
      this.effect,
      this.keep,
      this.tip,
      this.youtube01,
      this.youtube02,
      this.youtube03,
      this.season});

      Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : idx = json['idx'],
        name = json['name'],
        image = json['image'],
        kcal = json['kcal'],
        info = json['info'],
        effect = json['effect'],
        keep = json['keep'],
        tip = json['tip'],
        youtube01 = json['youtube01'],
        youtube02 = json['youtube02'],
        youtube03 = json['youtube03'],
        season = json['season'];

        Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'idx': idx,
        'name': name,
        'image': image,
        'kcal': kcal,
        'info': info,
        'effect': effect,
        'keep': keep,
        'tip': tip,
        'youtube01': youtube01,
        'youtube02': youtube02,
        'youtube03': youtube03,
              'season': season,
           };
     }
```

And this is the code structure of the body.

```
  void _dataBase() async {
    var ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance
        .ref("Info/")
        .orderByChild("season")
        .equalTo("january04");
    ref.onValue.listen((DatabaseEvent event) {
      dataJson = event.snapshot.value;
      //var jsonResult = jsonDecode(dataJson);
      var models = Model.fromJson(dataJson);
      //print(dataJson);
      print(models);
    });
  }
```

But I am getting this error in console.

"Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'"

Is the jsonparsing method wrong? No matter how you use jsonDecode or any method, an error appears.
please help me how to do it. Thank U.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value);`

Answer (score 0):

1st check response is null or not then do this :

```
 Map<dynamic, dynamic> toJson() => { //Change here 
        'idx': idx,
        'name': name,
        'image': image,
        'kcal': kcal,
        'info': info,
        'effect': effect,
        'keep': keep,
        'tip': tip,
        'youtube01': youtube01,
        'youtube02': youtube02,
        'youtube03': youtube03,
              'season': season,
           };
```